# ComboBox that adds to a ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I would need to have a ItemsControl with buttons for displaying the ItemSources. And I would need a comboBox to add items to the buttons to the ItemsSource. You choose an item from the comboBox and it gets added to the ItemsControl ItemsSource list. For example, I have a list of persons in the comboBox, I click one person on the comboBox and it is added to the ItemsContol Persons Binding. How can I achieve this ?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding FullName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"></ComboBox>
</ItemsControl>
```

The items control need to have Buttons for the persons and a comboBox to add persons from

[image: The items control with the persons]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` to a source property and then add an item to `Persons` collections in the setter of this one:

```
public List<Person> PersonToSelectFrom{ get; } = new List<Person>();

public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

private Person _selectedPerson;
public Person SelectedPerson
{
    get { return _selectedPerson; }
    set
    {
        _selectedPerson = value;
        if (_selectedPerson != null && !Persons.Contains(_selectedPerson))
            Persons.Add(_selectedPerson);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PersonToSelectFrom}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}" ... />
```

Note that the collection bound to the `ItemsControl` must implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface for the view to ge refreshed when you add an item to the source collection. The `ObservableCollection<T>` class does this but `List<T>` doesn't.

Comment: Is there a way to clear the comboBox after selecting the item ?

Comment: I have set _selectedPerson to null and called OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedPerson)); but that doesn't work

Comment: @JiexDrop: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.